# Find cells with same value within one column and return values from separate column of same row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find all the cells in `Column L` with a particular value and return the values in `Column D` of the same row as those cells found.

So far, I am only able to return one result, which would be the top most result in my list, but I want to find all the rest as well, which I don't know the code to use.

Just to further explain: Value in cell `D11` is the value I want to find in Column L of sheet "Master List". Supposedly I find the value in cells `L13`, `L15` and `L20`, I want to return the value in cell `D13`, `D15` and `D20` into cells "`C37:C39`" of ws. Note: no. of cells that have the value may vary so the values returned will just appear from `C37` downwards (something like automatic multiple selection, copy and paste)

Here's a little something to start the ball rolling:

```
Sub FindRelatedProducts()
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim D11Value As Variant
Dim D11Row As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("RShip")

Set cell = ws.Range("D11")
    D11Value = cell.Value
    With Sheets("Master List")
        D11Row = Application.Match(D11Value, .Range("L:L"), 0)
        If Not IsError(D11Row) Then
          ws.Range("C37") = .Range("D" & D11Row).Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using range variables.

You'll want to define a range for the input data range and a range for the output data.  Then in the VBA you will want to change the `wrk`, `inRng` and `outRng` variables to be the named ranges you defined and change the column indexes in the `for` and `if` blocks to match the column index of the data you are looking for.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub FindValues()
    Dim wrk As Worksheet
    Dim inRng As Range
    Dim outRng As Range

    Dim cntr As Long
    Dim outCntr As Long
    Dim findVal As Double

    Set wrk = Worksheets("Data")
    Set inRng = wrk.Range("LookupRange")
    Set outRng = wrk.Range("OutputRange")

    ' Clear the output range in case you have fewer values on this run than on the previous one
    outRng.ClearContents

    ' Set the value you are looking for
    findVal = 1

    ' Iterate through the rows in the input range.  If you find the result you want then write it to the output range
    For cntr = 1 To inRng.Rows.Count
        If inRng(cntr, 1) = findVal Then ' Assumes the value you are finding is in column 1 of the input range
            outRng(outCntr, 1) = inRng(cntr, 2) ' Assumes the values you are exporting is in column 2 of the input range
            outCntr = outCntr + 1
        End If
    Next cntr
End Sub
```